# cmake, build with /MD and find_package(Boost)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017, vcpkg

I have a library that is a Python extension (pyd) and to be able to debug it I need to compile with Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) Runtime Libraries.
This works great until I injected a Boost dependency. 
**But first time I call a Boost function the code crashes with a read access violation exception**.

[image]
[image]

After some investigation it turns out cmake find_package(Boost) pulls in the boost libraries build with a different run-time library i.e.boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd.lib

I have put this in an easy test case.

Build boost using vcpkg:
    git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
    .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
    vcpkg install boost

This only generates the -mt and -md-gd boost libraries.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6.3)
project (FindMDBoost CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MD")
file (GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "source.cpp")

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTI_THREADED OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(testcode ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(testcode ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

source.cpp

```
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
int main()
{   
    auto path = boost::filesystem::path("c:\\"); // Call  Boost to see if it crashes
}
```

Run cmake:

```
mkdir build; cd build    
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

As you can see in the output cmake still tried to find the wrong run time and ignores my Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS and Boost_USE_MULTI_THREADED flags!

```
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1078 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1080 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1082 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1084 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1086 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1088 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1156 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1158 ]   BOOST_ROOT = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1160 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1162 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1164 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1263 ] location of version.hpp: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1287 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.66.0
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1363 ] using user-specified Boost_COMPILER = -vc140
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1383 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1427 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1429 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1491 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1641 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_66;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_66;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-1_66;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-1_66;boost_filesystem-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1641 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc140-mt-1_66;boost_system-vc140-mt;boost_system-mt-1_66;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_66;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-1_66;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:380 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/debug/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
-- [ C:/install/cmake-3.10.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1767 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Boost version: 1.66.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/cpptests/FindMDBoost/build
```

Here is the [output](https://pastebin.com/cpbsgENX) from the linking phase.

**Update**: I build the boost libraries from scratch and the code stopped crashing. So this seems to be a vcpkg issue that is does not build the version of boost I need.
b2 runtime-link=shared -j16
My new CmakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6.3)
project (FindMDBoost CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MD")
file (GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "source.cpp")

include_directories(C:/dev/boost/boost_1_66_0)

link_directories("C:/dev/boost/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib")
add_executable(testcode ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(testcode libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x32-1_66.lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue just has to do with how you tell vcpkg to build boost when installing it. You can specify static or dynamic linking by specifying what they call [triplets](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/triplets/).

So for you: `vcpkg install boost --triplet x64-windows-static`

This will build the boost libraries for use with static linking.

Comment: You will also need to set `-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static` in your cmake configure line.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the library with an -mt is the correct one for linking to /MD ; confusingly the static library would have an s but does not seem what you want from the remarks at the beginning.  You were loading the mt-gd versions which are just the debug versions of these libraries; I suppose they expect the calling python to be the debug version as well.